# Tightly Couple SSH keys with a single Machine

Tags: linux, ssh, security, ssh-keys

I do have a ssh private key in my dev machine through which I can ssh into my production server. One security problem is that I can copy this ssh private key to any personal machine or say some machines in public internet cafe and login to the server. Can I tightly couple my SSH key with my dev system, such that the SSH key works only in that system. The server should identify and block the request if the SSH key is used from the other machines?

Comment: What mechanism would you use to identify your dev machine? A "host" key stored on your dev machine? But just like you can copy your private key to another computer, you could copy this host key to another computer ... You can secure your private key with a passphrase, though. That means even if copied, the person using it would need to know the passphrase.

Comment: @dirkt Passphrase is a good idea. Can MAC address be helpful to identify in the machine? Can the server block using the mac address ?

Comment: On basically all modern hardware you can set the MAC address. There may also be several network cards. And don't forget containers, virtual machines and their virtual network cards (with random MAC addresses).